# what can i do , if else is not working in gml?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language

The problem is if - else of gml , i have a conditional in if and it is true , so the else case must no enter, so in this case in the if and the else are working i dont know why. i have a global variable that is Turno. please check the code.

when i do click on a image it check if turno is 1 if turno is 1 so play a audio else do the switch case, but my code works both the if and the else case i dont know why.

THIS IS THE CODE OF ONE OBJECT AND THERE ARE ONE GLOBAL VARIABLE CREATED in this same  OBJECT LIKE

it is created in create event.

```
   Global.Turno = 1
```

this is the Left Button event. of the object.

```
 if(global.Turno == 1){
  global.Turno = global.Turno + 1 ; //ahora toca turno dos
  global.Logros = global.Logros + 1 ; // ya paso la prueba de turno uno
   // aqui reproducir el audio MUYY BIENNN.

   if(!audio_is_playing(snd_muy_bien)){
    audio_play_sound(snd_muy_bien,100,false);
   }

 }else{

  switch(global.Turno){
   case 1: {

      if( !audio_is_playing(snd_encuentra_la_cama) ){
         audio_play_sound(snd_encuentra_la_cama,100,false);
      }

    break;  
   }
    case 2 : {

    if( !audio_is_playing(snd_encuentra_el_televisor) ){
         audio_play_sound(snd_encuentra_el_televisor,100,false);
      }

    break;
 }

 case 3 : {

    if( !audio_is_playing(snd_encuentra_el_zapato) ){
         audio_play_sound(snd_encuentra_el_zapato,100,false);
      }   

    break;
 }

 case 4 : {

   if( !audio_is_playing(snd_encuentra_el_nino) ){
         audio_play_sound(snd_encuentra_el_nino,100,false);
      }

    break;
 }

 case 5 : {

    if( !audio_is_playing(snd_encuentra_el_ropero) ){
         audio_play_sound(snd_encuentra_el_ropero,100,false);
      }

       break;
 }

 case 6 : {

    if( !audio_is_playing(snd_encuentra_el_perro) ){
         audio_play_sound(snd_encuentra_el_perro,100,false);
      }

     break;
 }

 case 7 : {

   if( !audio_is_playing(snd_encuentra_la_ventana) ){
         audio_play_sound(snd_encuentra_la_ventana,100,false);
      }

    break;
 }



 default: {
     if(!audio_is_playing(snd_ya_has_ganau_felicidades)){
    audio_play_sound(snd_ya_has_ganau_felicidades,100,false);
   }
 }
  }


 }
```

THERE ARE NOT ERRORS , THE PROBLEM IS THAT BOTH IS WORKING THE IF AND THE ELSE CASE. I DONT KNOW WHY THANKS. IF YOU GUYS WANT MORE CODE PLEASE TELL ME THNAKS.

Comment: Do a couple show_debug_message calls to see what's getting called, check that you don't have "apply to object" set to something weird if you are using GMS1 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with @YellowAfterLife, but I do want to make note that you do have a default setting in your switch case

```
default: {
 if(!audio_is_playing(snd_ya_has_ganau_felicidades)){
audio_play_sound(snd_ya_has_ganau_felicidades,100,false);
```

}

Which means that it will play the music no matter what. Another reason could be variable scoping, although I don't think that it is the main reason behind your issue. You could check if it is by moving the ++ variable to the bottom as such:

```
 if(global.Turno == 1){
   if(!audio_is_playing(snd_muy_bien)){
   audio_play_sound(snd_muy_bien,100,false);
   }
   global.Turno = global.Turno + 1 ; //ahora toca turno dos
   global.Logros = global.Logros + 1 ; // ya paso la prueba de turno uno
 }
```